# Double Sesonal Holt-Winters methods for data containing zeros or negative numbers

Tags: r, time-series, multiple-seasonalities

I am trying to fit `dshw` for the double seasonal times series, and compare the results with `tbats()` , I used:

```
> dresid.train.dshw <- dshw(dresid.ts,h = 44)    
Error in dshw(dresid.ts, h = 44) : 
dshw not suitable when data contain zeros or negative numbers
```

It seems that `dshw` can not deal with negative or zero values. Does anyone know how to fit dshw on negative data?

Also, from a `dshw` example, the parameters (alpha, beta, gamma, omega, and phi) are specified in the model. I am wondering how those parameters are selected?

May I also know how to get confidence interval for the `dshw` forecast? As I can always extract `upper` and `lower` from the `forecast()` of a tbats model, but it seems that I can not find those in the `dshw`. Thanks.

Comment: An easy work around would be to add a large constant and run the method, on you obtain the forecast just subtract the constant.